# Mysqli query doesn't fetch results

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code, i would like to print a table with content. It prints table but the columns are empty... What am I missing? I cannot see the mistake..

```
function show_autovetture($data){

    $con = $data;               //PASSO CONNESSIONE
    $rows = array();            // PREPARO ARRAY

    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($con); // INIZIALIZZO LA CONNESSIONE

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,'SELECT
                        autovetture.id,
                        autovetture.name
                        FROM autovetture
                        ORDER BY id DESC');
                        or die(mysqli_error($con)); // QUERY INSERIMENTO DATI

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);                    // ESEGUO LA QUERY

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$rows['id'],$rows['name']);

    $html = "";
    $html .= "<div class='container'>";
    $html .= "<div class='div_box_5'>";
    $html .= "<div class='row'>";
    $html .= "<div class='panel panel-default'>";
    $html .= "<div class='panel-heading'>";
    $html .= "<h4>";
    $html .= "Elenco Ditte Autovetture"; 
    $html .= "</h4>";
    $html .= "</div> <!-- end panel-heading -->";
    $html .= "<table class='table table-fixed'>";
    $html .= "<thead>";
    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .= "<th class='col-xs-2'>#</th><th class='col-xs-8'>Nome</th><th class='col-xs-2'>Modifica</th>";
    $html .= "</tr>";
    $html .= "</thead>";
    $html .= "<tbody>";
    while($rows=mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
            $html .= "<tr>";
            $html .= "<td class='col-xs-2'>$rows[id]</td><td class='col-xs-8'>$rows[name]</td><td class='col-xs-2'><a href='edit_autovet.php?id=$rows[id]'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span></a></td>";
            $html .= "</tr>"; 
    }
    $html .= "</tbody>";
    $html .= "</table>";
    $html .= "</div> <!-- end panel panel-default -->";
    $html .= "</div> <!-- end row -->";
    $html .= "</div> <!-- end div_box_5 -->";
    $html .= "</div> <!-- end container -->";


    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);                                       // CHIUDO LO STATEMENT
    mysqli_close($con);                                             // CHIUDO CONNESSIONE   

    return $html;

}
```

Where is the error?

Comment: read how to check for mysqli errors

Comment: the problem is that i have no errors on screen.. how can I check them?

Comment: I found that mysqli had somewhat of a learning curve but once you get it, it is very robust. You can use http://php.net/mysqli_error `mysqli_error($link)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are already bound when you bind them with `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$rows['id'],$rows['name']);`, and they will be in those variables even when you loop - the contents of the variable will be updated for each iteration of the loop while fetching -  so you just want to loop with `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` as the argument, without assigning to a variable, like this

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
```

instead of

```
while($rows=mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
```

Fetching data is a bit different with using a statement than fetching using a `mysqli_fetch_*()` method.

You're currently overwriting the `$rows` variable, making it a boolean (true/false) or null when you run it like you currently are. See the manual of `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` for the return-values.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: Thanks you saved my day!, stupid mistake! thank you so much :)

Comment: Happy to help! :-) you can also use a regular query here, as you're not binding any placeholders (variables or user-input) in the query. But there's nothing wrong with preparing, it's just a little more work :-) *Cheers*